# Powermock tests pass when run seperate but fail in suite

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, easymock, powermock

I am using powermock + easymock + testng

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="My Module" suite-preserve-order="true" verbose="10"
    object-factory="org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory">  
    <test verbose="2" name="module1" annotations="JDK">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.mymodule.TestClass1" />
            <class name="com.mymodule.TestClass2" />
            <class name="com.mymodule.TestClass3" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Test1 & 2 works together. When i added Test3, they started failing with all sorts of errors like java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available

I fixed Test1 by adding annotation @PrepareEverythingForTest

But i am not able to fix test 2 & 3 which itself has started failing. Test 3 works fine individually. Its worth mentioning these classes share some mocked classes and themselves have been mocked in each other test case. By default i am using the annotation like

@PrepareOnlyThisForTest({TestClass2.class,SharedClass.class})

How can i fix these. Looks like some mockings are shared across the tests.
How to stop it.

Please reply

Comment: Please provide the relevant parts of code.  It's obvious you are not doing proper setup and/or cleanup.